# Access DOM Properties in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, typescript, angular

I've implemented a progress bar and displayed the percentage of progress bar in the html by accessing the width property of the progress bar using document.getElementsByClassName . But what should i use to implement this in Angular 2, which uses typescript.

Working HTML and JS code : https://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/2cy2kg7y/1/

Angular 2 Code (should be fixed): https://plnkr.co/edit/nlRa0aaQv7GntxxBy8AC?p=preview

html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-fill"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="progress"></div>
```

JS code:

```
var
  bar = document.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0],
  barFill = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-fill")[0],
  progress = document.getElementById("progress"),
  barWidth = window.getComputedStyle(bar, null).getPropertyValue("width"),
  barFillWidth = window.getComputedStyle(barFill, null).getPropertyValue("width"),
  pct = 100 * (parseFloat(barFillWidth) / parseFloat(barWidth)) + "%";

progress.innerHTML = pct;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ngStyle so you could dynamically update the progress bar percentage and display to the users.

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-fill" [ngStyle]="{'width': progressPercentage + '%'}">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="progress">{{progressPercentage}}%</div>
```

TypeScript Code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'progressbar',
    styleUrls: ['./progressbar.component.css'],
    templateUrl: './progressbar.component.html'

})
export class ProgressBar{
    progressPercentage: number;

    constructor() {
      this.progressPercentage = 50;
    }
}
```

plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/LytbNF5HdDYUAxBUYenf?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that's the easiest answer, i haven't thought this way. Thanks for the asnwer

Comment: I was thinking of using ElementRef with querySelector. Do you know any other way of doing this?